# Making table notes aligned with the table width

Tags: tablenotes

I am using the threepart table environment to create tables. I use `tablenotes` for my table notes. However, the table notes cross the table width. How do I contain the notes within the table width. I also use `flushleft` for left alignment. Here is the part of the code for table notes:

```
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
    \small 
    \item\leavevmode\kern-\scriptspace\kern-\labelsep \textit{Notes:} Table Notes. Standard errors clustered at the XXXXX level. */**/*** denotes significance at the 10/5/1 percent levels.
    \item hgahgalhgalghlsghslhga hglahlllllll lllllllllll llllllllllllllllllll lllllllllllllllhalhgaghal halghalgha galghalhg
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
```

Full MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[bottom,hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
%\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}, bookmarksnumbered=true, bookmarksopenlevel=1, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=BrickRed, urlcolor=BrickRed, citecolor=Blue, hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}, bookmarksnumbered=true, bookmarksopenlevel=1, colorlinks=true, allcolors=BrickRed, citecolor=Blue, hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage[blocks, auth-sc, affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsf}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage[position=top]{subfig}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bigdelim}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\captionsetup{margin=10pt,font=large,labelfont={bf,large},position=below,justification=justified}

%\usepackage{etoc}

%\externaldocument{MigSim_Appendix_Final}
%\setlength{\affilsep}{0pt}


%\usepackage{geometry}
%\geometry{left=.95in,right=.95in,top=.925in,bottom=.925in}

%\usepackage{titling}
%\settowidth{\thanksmarkwidth}{*}
%\setlength{\thanksmargin}{-\thanksmarkwidth}

\newcommand{\nocontentsline}[3]{}
\newcommand{\tocless}[2]{\bgroup\let\addcontentsline=\nocontentsline#1{#2}\egroup}

\newcommand\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\prob}[1][P]{\ensuremath {\mathbb{#1}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\expect}[0]{{\mathbb E}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\variance}[0]{{\mathbb V}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\indicator}[0]{{\mathbbm 1}}
\newcommand{\Var}{\mathbb{V}}
\newcommand{\Cov}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\var}{\mathrm{Var}}
\newcommand{\cov}{\mathrm{Cov}}
\newcommand{\plim}{\mathrm{plim}}
\newcommand{\indep}{\perp\!\!\!\perp}

%\renewcommand{\sout}{\vphantom}

%\renewcommand*\thetable{\Roman{table}}
%\renewcommand*\thefigure{\Roman{figure}}

\newcommand{\ag}{\color{OliveGreen}}
\newcommand{\agt}[1]{{\color{OliveGreen}#1}}
\newcommand{\agst}[1]{{\color{OliveGreen}\sout{#1}}}

\newcommand{\mpc}{\color{Red}}
\newcommand{\mpt}[1]{{\color{Red}#1}}
\newcommand{\mpst}[1]{{\color{Red}\sout{#1}}}


\renewcommand{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{5pt}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\normalfont\scshape}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\normalfont\bfseries}


\newdateformat{monthyeardate}{\monthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR}

\newcommand{\stoptocwriting}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-5}}}
\newcommand{\resumetocwriting}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{\arabic{tocdepth}}}}

\providecommand\phantomsection{}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}[lemma]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{assumption}[lemma]{Assumption}

\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\newcommand{\seper}{\setlength{\itemsep}}

\floatsetup[table]{style=plaintop}


\begin{table}[htbp!]
    \begin{threeparttable}[b]
        \caption{Treatment Effects With New Strategy}
        \scalebox{0.75}{
    \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{8pt}}lccccccccc@{}} \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{Avg Test Score} &
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{Avg Passing Rate} &
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{Avg Participation Rate} \\\\
        \cline{2-4}
        \cline{5-7}
        \cline{8-10}

VARIABLES   & Male       & Female   & All       & Male          & Female    & All       & Male      & Female& All \\ 

            &     (1)    & (2)      & (3)       & (4)           & (5)       & (6)       & (7)       & (8)   & (9) \\

\hline
            &               &               &                   &           &           &           &       &   &\\

Treatment   &      -26.21   &      -22.18   &       34.08*  &       35.83*  &      -59.34*  &       17.13   &      -26.21   &        9.84   &       -8.46   \\
            &     [-2.02]   &     [-0.50]   &      [2.42]   &      [2.23]   &     [-2.46]   &      [1.22]   &     [-2.02]   &      [1.24]   &     [-0.78]   \\
            &     (13.00)   &     (44.77)   &     (14.06)   &     (16.04)   &     (24.12)   &     (14.03)   &     (13.00)   &      (7.93)   &     (10.82)   \\
Post        &      -26.50** &      -25.47   &      -11.53   &       40.49***&       52.71***&       52.68***&      -26.50** &        2.28   &      -16.49*  \\
            &     [-3.52]   &     [-1.35]   &     [-1.34]   &      [4.36]   &      [5.18]   &      [6.15]   &     [-3.52]   &      [0.68]   &     [-2.49]   \\
            &      (7.52)   &     (18.90)   &      (8.59)   &      (9.28)   &     (10.18)   &      (8.57)   &      (7.52)   &      (3.35)   &      (6.61)   \\
DiD         &       29.65*  &       31.22   &        5.33   &        9.17   &      141.80** &       11.56   &       29.65*  &      -15.08   &        1.07   \\
            &      [2.13]   &      [0.39]   &      [0.32]   &      [0.53]   &      [3.25]   &      [0.70]   &      [2.13]   &     [-1.05]   &      [0.08]   \\
            &     (13.89)   &     (80.90)   &     (16.45)   &     (17.14)   &     (43.58)   &     (16.42)   &     (13.89)   &     (14.34)   &     (12.67)   \\
Constant    &       42.02   &      271.27*  &      222.43***&       65.29*  &      -23.66   &      -38.16   &       42.02   &       23.55   &      -46.42   \\
            &      [1.87]   &      [2.58]   &      [6.20]   &      [2.36]   &     [-0.42]   &     [-1.07]   &      [1.87]   &      [1.26]   &     [-1.68]   \\
            &     (22.46)   &    (105.12)   &     (35.85)   &     (27.71)   &     (56.63)   &     (35.78)   &     (22.46)   &     (18.63)   &     (27.59)   \\
Obs         &       39.00   &       38.00   &       47.00   &       39.00   &       38.00   &       47.00   &       39.00   &       38.00   &       47.00   \\ \\ \hline 
    \end{tabular}}
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
        \small 
        \item \textit{Notes:} Table Notes. Standard errors clustered at 
        the XXXXX level. */**/*** denotes significance at the 10/5/1 percent levels. The outcome variable is the share of observations that passed the intervention 
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

[image: Screenshot of output with table not overflowing into the page margin.]

Here is the output I am getting. All I need to do is to make my table note aligned with the table. Now even it is crossing the page margin.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. How wide is the `tabular` environment associated with the `threeparttable` environment? Also, what's the purpose of `\leavevmode\kern-\scriptspace\kern-\labelsep`? Does the issue you wish to fix persist if you remove this group of instructions? Does the issue persist if you replace strings such as `lllllllllllllllhalhgaghal` with human-parsable words?

Comment: Please extend your code fragment  to MWE (Minimal Working Example, a complete but small document) which demonstrate your problem. Wot usual (standard) use of `table notes with breakable words, you problem shouldn't happen.

Comment: The problem persists even if I remove those groups of instructions.

Comment: Here is my complete working code:

Comment: The reason for the tablenotes being wider than the table itself iy our use of the `\scalebox` command. Remove this and try to reduce thefont size and/or the tabcolsep to make sure the table fits into the textwidth. `tabular*` might also come in handy.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the tablenotes being wider than the table itself os the use of `\scalebox`. To make sure that the table fits into the textwidth, I have used a smaller font size in combination with `tabular*`. I have alsi replaced the horizontal lines with the lines from the `booktabs` package (that you already load). In the following example, I have also decluttered the preamble and only kept packages that are related to the specific table:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{palatino}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{margin=10pt,font=large,labelfont={bf,large},position=below,justification=justified}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}



\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp!]
    \begin{threeparttable}[b]
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    \small
        \caption{Treatment Effects With New Strategy}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lccccccccc@{}} 
    \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{Avg Test Score} &
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{Avg Passing Rate} &
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{Avg Participation Rate} \\
        \cmidrule{2-4}
        \cmidrule{5-7}
        \cmidrule{8-10}

VARIABLES   & Male       & Female   & All       & Male          & Female    & All       & Male      & Female& All \\ 

            &     (1)    & (2)      & (3)       & (4)           & (5)       & (6)       & (7)       & (8)   & (9) \\

\midrule
            &               &               &                   &           &           &           &       &   &\\

Treatment   &      -26.21   &      -22.18   &       34.08*  &       35.83*  &      -59.34*  &       17.13   &      -26.21   &        9.84   &       -8.46   \\
            &     [-2.02]   &     [-0.50]   &      [2.42]   &      [2.23]   &     [-2.46]   &      [1.22]   &     [-2.02]   &      [1.24]   &     [-0.78]   \\
            &     (13.00)   &     (44.77)   &     (14.06)   &     (16.04)   &     (24.12)   &     (14.03)   &     (13.00)   &      (7.93)   &     (10.82)   \\
Post        &      -26.50** &      -25.47   &      -11.53   &       40.49***&       52.71***&       52.68***&      -26.50** &        2.28   &      -16.49*  \\
            &     [-3.52]   &     [-1.35]   &     [-1.34]   &      [4.36]   &      [5.18]   &      [6.15]   &     [-3.52]   &      [0.68]   &     [-2.49]   \\
            &      (7.52)   &     (18.90)   &      (8.59)   &      (9.28)   &     (10.18)   &      (8.57)   &      (7.52)   &      (3.35)   &      (6.61)   \\
DiD         &       29.65*  &       31.22   &        5.33   &        9.17   &      141.80** &       11.56   &       29.65*  &      -15.08   &        1.07   \\
            &      [2.13]   &      [0.39]   &      [0.32]   &      [0.53]   &      [3.25]   &      [0.70]   &      [2.13]   &     [-1.05]   &      [0.08]   \\
            &     (13.89)   &     (80.90)   &     (16.45)   &     (17.14)   &     (43.58)   &     (16.42)   &     (13.89)   &     (14.34)   &     (12.67)   \\
Constant    &       42.02   &      271.27*  &      222.43***&       65.29*  &      -23.66   &      -38.16   &       42.02   &       23.55   &      -46.42   \\
            &      [1.87]   &      [2.58]   &      [6.20]   &      [2.36]   &     [-0.42]   &     [-1.07]   &      [1.87]   &      [1.26]   &     [-1.68]   \\
            &     (22.46)   &    (105.12)   &     (35.85)   &     (27.71)   &     (56.63)   &     (35.78)   &     (22.46)   &     (18.63)   &     (27.59)   \\
Obs         &       39.00   &       38.00   &       47.00   &       39.00   &       38.00   &       47.00   &       39.00   &       38.00   &       47.00   \\ \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular*}
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
        \footnotesize 
        \item \textit{Notes:} Table Notes. Standard errors clustered at 
        the XXXXX level. */**/*** denotes significance at the 10/5/1 percent levels. The outcome variable is the share of observations that passed the intervention 
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

The following screenshot shows that the table is as wide as the textwidth (red lines mark the margins):

[image]

Comment: Thanks @leandriis. It worked but now my it does not flushleft - I mean the table is not left-aligned.  I did not get what you mean by "I have alsi replaced the horizontal lines with the lines from the booktabs package (that you already load)."

Comment: @Ahmad: I have editedd my aswer to include a second screenshot that shows that the table is as wide as the textwidth and therefore is aligned with the following dummy test that I added to the MWE.

Comment: Regarding the lines: In your code, you used `\hline` on combination with some empty lines (`\\\\ `). I have removed the empty rows and replaced `\hline` with `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` as well as `\cline` with `\cmidrule`. All the mentioned commands ending on ..rule are from the `booktabs` package that was already in the preamble of your original example. There horizontal lines have a small white space above and below them to prevent the surrounding text to touch the line.

Comment: Thanks, leandriis. It was helpful

Answer (score 1):

Some improvements with `siunitx`, `mathpazo` to fit the main font, and `makecell`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{mathpazo} 
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{
labelfont={bf,large}, skip =6pt}

\usepackage[margin=2cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp!]
\sisetup{table-format = -2.2, table-space-text-pre={[}, table-align-text-pre=false, table-space-text-post={***}, detect-family}
    \begin{threeparttable}[b] 
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    \small
        \caption{Treatment Effects With New Strategy}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}p{2cm}*{9}{S}@{}}
    \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{Avg Test Score} &
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{Avg Passing Rate} &
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{Avg Participation Rate} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
        \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
        \cmidrule(lr){8-10}

VARIABLES & {\thead{Male\\(1)}} &{\thead{Female\\(2)}} & {\thead{All\\(3)}} & {\thead{Male\\(4)}} & {\thead{Female\\(5)}} & {\thead{All\\(6)}} & {\thead{Male\\(7)}} & {\thead{Female\\(8)}} &{\thead{All\\(9)}} \\
\midrule
 \addlinespace[2ex]
Treatment & -26.21 & -22.18 & 34.08* & 35.83* & -59.34* & 17.13 & -26.21 & 9.84 & -8.46 \\
            & [-2.02] & [-0.50] & [2.42] & {[}2.23] & [-2.46] & [1.22] & [-2.02] & [1.24] & [-0.78] \\
            & {(}13.00{)} & {(}44.77{)} & {(}14.06{)} & {(}16.04{)} & {(}24.12{)} & {(}14.03{)} & {(}13.00{)} & {(}7.93{)} & {(}10.82{)} \\
\addlinespace
Post & -26.50** & -25.47 & -11.53 & 40.49***& 52.71***& 52.68***& -26.50** & 2.28 & -16.49* \\
            & [-3.52] & [-1.35] & [-1.34] & [4.36] & [5.18] & [6.15] & [-3.52] & [0.68] & [-2.49] \\
            & {(}7.52{)} & {(}18.90{)} & {(}8.59{)} & {(}9.28{)} & {(}10.18{)} & {(}8.57{)} & {(}7.52{)} & {(}3.35{)} & {(}6.61{)} \\
\addlinespace
DiD & 29.65* & 31.22 & 5.33 & 9.17 & 141.80** & 11.56 & 29.65* & -15.08 & 1.07 \\
            & [2.13] & [0.39] & [0.32] & [0.53] & [3.25] & [0.70] & [2.13] & [-1.05] & [0.08] \\
            & {(}13.89{)} & {(}80.90{)} & {(}16.45{)} & {(}17.14{)} & {(}43.58{)} & {(}16.42{)} & {(}13.89{)} & {(}14.34{)} & {(}12.67{)} \\
\addlinespace
Constant & 42.02 & 271.27* & 222.43***& 65.29* & -23.66 & -38.16 & 42.02 & 23.55 & -46.42 \\
            & [1.87] & [2.58] & [6.20] & [2.36] & [-0.42] & [-1.07] & [1.87] & [1.26] & [-1.68] \\
            & {(}22.46{)} & {(}105.12{)} & {(}35.85{)} & {(}27.71{)} & {(}56.63{)} & {(}35.78{)} & {(}22.46{)} & {(}18.63{)} & {(}27.59{)} \\
\addlinespace
Obs & 39.00 & 38.00 & 47.00 & 39.00 & 38.00 & 47.00 & 39.00 & 38.00 & 47.00 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
\smallskip
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
        \footnotesize
        \item \textit{Notes:} Table Notes. Standard errors clustered at
        the XXXXX level. */**/*** denotes significance at the 10/5/1 percent levels. The outcome variable is the share of observations that passed the intervention
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Small variation of @Bernard answer. Changed is `siunitx` setup, consequently a way how numbers in parenthesis are written in table body and instead `threeparttable` is used `[referable]{threeparttablex}`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont={bf,large}, skip =6pt}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}    % <---
\usepackage{siunitx}

%---------------- show page layoutdon't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp!]
\sisetup{table-format = -2.2, 
         input-symbols = {( )},     % <---
         table-space-text-pre={[}, 
         table-align-text-pre=false, 
         table-space-text-post={***}, 
         detect-family}
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    \small
        \caption{Treatment Effects With New Strategy}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}p{2cm}*{9}{S}@{}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Avg Test Score} 
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Avg Passing Rate} 
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Avg Participation Rate}    \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-10}
VARIABLES 
    & {\thead{Male\\(1)}}   & {\thead{Female\\(2)}} & {\thead{All\\(3)}} 
    & {\thead{Male\\(4)}}   & {\thead{Female\\(5)}} & {\thead{All\\(6)}} 
    & {\thead{Male\\(7)}}   & {\thead{Female\\(8)}} & {\thead{All\\(9)}}    \\
\midrule
Treatment 
    & -26.21    & -22.18    & 34.08*    & 35.83*    & -59.34*   
    &  17.13    & -26.21    & 9.84      & -8.46                             \\
    & [-2.02]   & [-0.50]   & [2.42]    & [2.23]    & [-2.46] 
    & [1.22]    & [-2.02]   & [1.24]    & [-0.78]                           \\
    & (13.00) & (44.77) & (14.06) & (16.04)
    & (24.12) & (14.03) & (13.00) & (7.93) & (10.82) \\
\addlinespace
Post & -26.50** & -25.47 & -11.53 & 40.49***& 52.71***& 52.68***& -26.50** & 2.28 & -16.49* \\
            & [-3.52] & [-1.35] & [-1.34] & [4.36] & [5.18] & [6.15] & [-3.52] & [0.68] & [-2.49] \\
            & (7.52) & (18.90) & (8.59) & (9.28) & (10.18) & (8.57) & (7.52) & (3.35) & (6.61) \\
\addlinespace
DiD & 29.65* & 31.22 & 5.33 & 9.17 & 141.80** & 11.56 & 29.65* & -15.08 & 1.07 \\
            & [2.13] & [0.39] & [0.32] & [0.53] & [3.25] & [0.70] & [2.13] & [-1.05] & [0.08] \\
            & (13.89) & (80.90) & (16.45) & (17.14) & (43.58) & (16.42) & (13.89) & (14.34) & (12.67) \\
\addlinespace
Constant & 42.02 & 271.27* & 222.43***& 65.29* & -23.66 & -38.16 & 42.02 & 23.55 & -46.42 \\
            & [1.87] & [2.58] & [6.20] & [2.36] & [-0.42] & [-1.07] & [1.87] & [1.26] & [-1.68] \\
            & (22.46) & (105.12) & (35.85) & (27.71) & (56.63) & (35.78) & (22.46) & (18.63) & (27.59) \\
\addlinespace
Obs & 39.00 & 38.00 & 47.00 & 39.00 & 38.00 & 47.00 & 39.00 & 38.00 & 47.00 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
\smallskip
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
    \note Table Notes. Standard errors clustered at
        the XXXXX level. */**/*** denotes significance at the 10/5/1 percent levels. The outcome variable is the share of observations that passed the intervention
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

**Note:** you could consider to use the macro `\tnote` for writing notes in table.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ Zarko. How do I make my notes numbered? I used \item for each note. The numbering of the notes start from the second line not right from the first line

Comment: @Ahmad, sorry, I don't understand you. Which notes? Significance? Please elaborate.

Comment: Zarko, I found a way to do it. I was asking how do I make enumerated notes using \item. But I could do it by adding numbers in square brackets.

Comment: I am using Stata estout command to prepare my tables. I am struggling with how to insert lines between variables and statistics or anywhere in the table in Stata so that I do not have to edit my Latex files anytime I change my regression specifications. I can share my code if it helps.

Comment: @Ahmad, sorry, I do not understand you. Which lines? All lines which are needed are shown in my answer. I'm not familiar with Stata, so anything regarding it I'm not right address for help. Also this is not part of your question. I haven't any idea, if in Stata is possible to include instruction for design of tables. About this is better to ask a new question. Your question as it is, is solved somehow in received answers. Now is time, that you select one, which fulfil your expectation on the best way and than accept it. :-)

Comment: thanks. The Latex problem is solved. The answers here helped me figure it out. As you said, I will create a new question related to my Stata question.

Comment: You could choose among of answers one that helped you the most.